# MySQL (innodb) Prevent Circular Reference

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I have an object `Permissions` that has a column for `InheritedPermissions` which references another object of the same type - theoretically you could continue this chain forever.  I want to make sure that when adding or changing the value of `InheritedPermissions` that it never creates a circular reference.

I imagine I will have to do this through a series of checks either in a Stored Procedure or inside the client code (I know how to do this) - however, since there is a lot about SQL that I don't know (Triggers, Options, etc...) I wanted to double check:

Is there a way to setup the table that will simply disallow the reference if a circular reference would be created?

I am using MySQL and innodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into MySQL to prevent a circular reference like what you describe.  You are stuck with writing tedious code.

Comment: Thanks, not what I wanted to hear, but the answer I was expecting!